# is there an ordinal to cardinal function in ruby or rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, cardinality, ordinals

I'm trying to find a better way in expressing my cucumbers so I am looking for an ordinal to cardinal function that converts this:

```
When I fill up the first passenger field
Then I should see the passenger list update with the first passenger details
When I follow "Add Another Passenger"
Then I should see a second passenger field
When I fill up the second passenger field
Then I should see the passenger list update with the second passenger details
```

into something more dynamic(instead of creating separate steps for each line)

here's a sample of my web steps

```
When /^I fill up the first passenger field$/ do
  fill_in("booking_passengers_attributes_0_first_name", :with => "Blah")
  fill_in("booking_passengers_attributes_0_last_name", :with => "blah")
  select("5' to 6'", :from => "booking_passengers_attributes_0_height")
  select("100 to 150lbs", :from => "booking_passengers_attributes_0_weight")
end

When /^I fill up the second passenger field$/ do
  fill_in("booking_passengers_attributes_1_first_name", :with => "Wee")
  fill_in("booking_passengers_attributes_1_last_name", :with => "Sir")
  select("5' to 6'", :from => "booking_passengers_attributes_1_height")
  select("150 to 200lbs", :from => "booking_passengers_attributes_1_weight")
end
```

See that 0 and 1? I wish to convert "first" to a cardinal number so i can just substitute. You can also just suggest a better way to declare the cukes :)

**UPDATED ANSWER**
I am in the middle of refactoring but basically I used 1st instead of first and used to_i on that.

```
When /^I fill up the "([^"]*)" passenger field$/ do |id|
  input_id = id.to_i - 1
  fill_in("booking_passengers_attributes_#{input_id}_first_name", :with => id)
  fill_in("booking_passengers_attributes_#{input_id}_last_name", :with => "Passenger")
  select("5' to 6'", :from => "booking_passengers_attributes_#{input_id}_height")
  select("100 to 150lbs", :from => "booking_passengers_attributes_#{input_id}_weight")  
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the short-form, easily-parsable ordinal:

```
When /^I fill up the (\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th) passenger field$/ do |n|
  # etc...
end
```

Comment: yeah I figured I could use that. much better without the st|nd|rd|th though, i could just use n.to_i and convert it immediately to a number. thanks for the heads up!

Comment: In case anyone else runs into an issue with this, you should use (?:st|nd|rd|th) so that it's not "|th passenger field" (which incorrectly will match "I fill up the 1st")

Answer (score 19):

i dont really completely understand,exactly what you want to do, but you can do something like this with active support:

```
 1.ordinalize    # => "1st"
  2.ordinalize    # => "2nd"
  1002.ordinalize # => "1002nd"
```

and there is a  action view helper number_in_words to get "first" , "second" etc

i don't know much about cukes sorry,

Comment: i wanted something the other way around where i say: something like "first".to_cardinal # => "1" or something

Comment: I don't see `number_in_words` in the docs and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: `ordinalize` works like a charm, but I can't find `number_in_words` anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

This function is built into [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic):

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'chronic'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Chronic::Numerizer.numerize("eighty-fifth").to_i
=> 85
```